# Infinitely printing line

Tags: python, while-loop, printing, infinite

I'm trying to implement a number guesser and getting an infinitely printing line ("FAILURE") once the input hits the limit without a correct answer.

I am struggling to stop this infinite printing without breaking the actual game. Here is my code:

```
cntr =0
n=input("The magic number is - ")

while n!="6":
    cntr +=1
    if cntr <4:
        n=input("No, try again ... ")
    elif cntr ==4:
        n = input("Last chance ")
    else:
        print("FAILURE")
print ("Yes, the num was '6'")
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Note that if you get to your 'else' case, the user will no longer have the ability to change `n`. Thus, the `while` loop condition to stop (`n == 6`) will never be triggered. If you get to the `FAILURE` case you want to use `break` to break out of your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not breaking the while loop in case all attempts are made. You have to break the loop and check, outside of it, if the attempts have reached the limit or if the value has been hit. Your code should look like this:

```
cntr = 0
n = input("The magic number is - ")

while n!="6":
    cntr += 1
    if cntr <4:
        n = input("No, try again ... ")
    elif cntr ==4:
        n = input("Last chance ")
    else: break
if(n != "6"):
  print("FAILURE")
else:
  print ("Yes, the num was '6'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to go through your program and you will realize that incrementing the variable cntr (I suppose this is your counter for the while loop) does not have an impact on when the while loop will be stopped.
*Hint:*
Check your two if statements and your while condition.